# Google Analytics 4: pageviews by month and year

Tags: google-analytics-4

In a report:

With some difficulty (it was much simpler with Universal Analytics) I was able to select two Dimensions: Month and Year and one Metric: Views.

However the chart does not seem to be customizable. It only takes the Month (not the Year), and shows one series per Month.

In Universal Analytics it was possible.

How can I create a report showing pageviews by month and year (e.g. 123,456 Views for 09/2023) with a Line chart that shows pageviews in Y axis and each month/year in X axis?

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to produce such a report in the Explorations section of GA4, this isn't going to be ideal. The Explorations use "live" data which GA4 only retains for a limited period and the default is 2 months (with 14 months as the maximum).

This would mean your month/year report is going to be far more limited than it would be in Universal Analytics.

In my experience, the easiest way to get what you want is to use [Looker Studio](https://lookerstudio.google.com/) (the new name for Google's Data Studio). You simply link your Analytics property to the report, add a table or a chart, select the dimensions (month and year - in fact *Year Month* is a specific dimension available through Looker Studio), the metrics you want to report, and the timeframe you need, and Bob's your uncle.